# Consuming JSON in C# from mailchimp campaignEmailStatsAIMAll

Tags: c#, json, mailchimp

I am trying to program .net c# code to read the results from a call to `campaignEmailStatsAIMAll()`.

Here is a sample of the JSON results I get:

```
{
   "total":3,
   "data":{
      "some...@company.com":[
         {
            "action":"click",
            "timestamp":"2012-10-18 20:55:52",
            "url":"http:\/\/www.someurl.com?ct=t(First_Chimp_Test10_18_2012)",
            "ip":"66.66.666.666"
         },
         {
            "action":"open",
            "timestamp":"2012-10-18 20:55:52",
            "url":null,
            "ip":"66.66.666.666"
         }
      ],
      "anothe...@corporation.com":[
         {
            "action":"open",
            "timestamp":"2012-10-18 20:18:05",
            "url":null,
            "ip":"22.222.222.222"
         },
         {
            "action":"open",
            "timestamp":"2012-10-18 20:18:18",
            "url":null,
            "ip":"22.222.222.222"
         },
         {
            "action":"click",
            "timestamp":"2012-10-18 20:18:18",
            "url":"http:\/\/www.someurl.com?ct=t(First_Chimp_Test10_18_2012)",
            "ip":"22.222.222.222"
         },
         {
            "action":"click",
            "timestamp":"2012-10-18 20:21:57",
            "url":"http:\/\/www.someurl.com?ct=t(First_Chimp_Test10_18_2012)",
            "ip":"22.222.222.222"
         }
      ],
      "thir...@business.com":[

      ]
   }
}
```

The problem I am having is how to define the C# object to accept this JSON string.  The email addresses are being treated as the name part of a JSON name/value pair.  I know there are 3rd party wrappers for .NET but I only want to call this API (maybe a couple of others down the line) and would prefer to code it myself.  I want to be able to iterate through the object to extract the email address then action/timestamp/url for each one.

When I drop this JSON into the object creator at json2sharp.com, I get this:

```
public class SomebodyCompanyCom {     
   public string action { get; set; }     
   public string timestamp { get; set; }     
   public string url { get; set; }     
   public string ip { get; set; } 
}

public class AnotherpersonCorporationCom {     
   public string action { get; set; }      
   public string timestamp { get; set; }     
   public string url { get; set; }     
   public string ip { get; set; } 
}

public class Data {     
   public List<SomebodyCompanyCom> __invalid_name__somebody@company.com { get; set; }     
   public List<AnotherpersonCorporationCom> __invalid_name__anotherperson@corporation.com { get; set; }     
   public List<object> __invalid_name__thirdguy@business.com { get; set; } 
}

public class RootObject {     
   public int total { get; set; }     
   public Data data { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A generator like that can only ever make best-guesses.  Since JSON is generally schema-less, you need to analyze the data and figure out the best way to model it.

In your case, you have two basic types:

1. the individual entries consisting of action, timestamp, url, and ip
2. the overall container with total and data

A reasonable model might look like this:

```
public class ItemInfo {     
   public string action { get; set; }     
   public string timestamp { get; set; }     
   public string url { get; set; }     
   public string ip { get; set; } 
}

public class ContainerType {
    public int total;
    public Dictionary<string, ItemInfo[]> data;
}
```

If you use a decent JSON library like [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx), you could deserialize the JSON string into an ContatinerType structure like so:

```
string rawJsonString = MagicallyGetTheJsonFromAWebservice();
ContainerType container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContainerType>(rawJsonString);
```

<s>It might need a bit of tweaking to get the type deserialization to work exactly, but</s> that's the basic idea.

Edit: sample console program to do the deserialization:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string testData = @"{
   'total':3,
   'data':{
      'some...@company.com':[
         {
            'action':'click',
            'timestamp':'2012-10-18 20:55:52',
            'url':'http:\/\/www.someurl.com?ct=t(First_Chimp_Test10_18_2012)',
            'ip':'66.66.666.666'
         },
         {
            'action':'open',
            'timestamp':'2012-10-18 20:55:52',
            'url':null,
            'ip':'66.66.666.666'
         }
      ],
      'anothe...@corporation.com':[
         {
            'action':'open',
            'timestamp':'2012-10-18 20:18:05',
            'url':null,
            'ip':'22.222.222.222'
         },
         {
            'action':'open',
            'timestamp':'2012-10-18 20:18:18',
            'url':null,
            'ip':'22.222.222.222'
         },
         {
            'action':'click',
            'timestamp':'2012-10-18 20:18:18',
            'url':'http:\/\/www.someurl.com?ct=t(First_Chimp_Test10_18_2012)',
            'ip':'22.222.222.222'
         },
         {
            'action':'click',
            'timestamp':'2012-10-18 20:21:57',
            'url':'http:\/\/www.someurl.com?ct=t(First_Chimp_Test10_18_2012)',
            'ip':'22.222.222.222'
         }
      ],
      'thir...@business.com':[

      ]
   }
}";

        public class ItemInfo {     
           public string action { get; set; }     
           public string timestamp { get; set; }     
           public string url { get; set; }     
           public string ip { get; set; } 
        }

        public class ContainerType {
            public int total;
            public Dictionary<string, ItemInfo[]> data;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ContainerType container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContainerType>(testData);
            if((container.total != 3)
                || (container.data.Count != 3)
                || (container.data["some...@company.com"][1].action != "open")
                || (container.data["anothe...@corporation.com"][2].url != "http://www.someurl.com?ct=t(First_Chimp_Test10_18_2012)"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully deserialized");
            }

            foreach (string email in container.data.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(email);
                for (int x = 0; x < container.data[email].Count(); x++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + x.ToString() + ":");
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\taction   : " + container.data[email][x].action);
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\ttimestamp: " + container.data[email][x].timestamp);
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\turl      : " + container.data[email][x].url);
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\tip       : " + container.data[email][x].ip);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you'd be hard-pressed to argue that it is not a dictionary - the way it is represented in the JSON is the canonical way to serialize a dictionary.  Regardless, the question is how to model the data in C# static types, and I believe this is the most efficient way.

Comment: I've got a test program I can post.  The point of my post is that the Data class is inappropriate for the data, and he should not have multiple types defined for each entry.

Comment: Thanks for the sample.  It works, but... can I access the information in container.data via an index like container.data[0][1].action (which does not work) since the email addresses being returned to me (some...@company.com, anothe...@corporation.com") are unknown, i.e. they will be different each time.  I want to find out what the email address is and then find out the action, url, etc. from ItemInfo.

Comment: I'll edit the answer to show how to iterate through the results

Comment: Great!  Welcome to StackOverflow!  Don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer if it's your preferred solution...

Comment: I'd appreciate it if someone would explain their reasoning for the downvote.